# How to replace/remove Square brackets & bouble quotes from python LIST

Tags: python, list, set, python-re

I need to remove Square Brackets from list of list (list contains sub list's)

```py
list = [["'deliver","'ordered","'delivery","'delivering","'brought"],["'deliver","'offering","'providing","'delivers","'orders"]]
```

Sample output

```py
list = 'deliver','ordered','delivery','delivering','brought'
```

Comment: What is the exact output you want?  A string?  A 1D list?  Something else?

Comment: What about the 2nd item in the list?

Comment: I need 1D only , every word in single quotes

Comment: for l in lst:
    [re.sub("'",'',i) for i in l]
print(new_lst)

note: don't use list. use a different name like lst, b/c list is a built-in python method

Answer (score 0):

Play with list comprehension, thats what its there for

```
[print(i) for i in [','.join(x).replace("'",'').split(',') for  x in lst]]

['deliver', 'ordered', 'delivery', 'delivering', 'brought']
['deliver', 'offering', 'providing', 'delivers', 'orders']
```

Or you could just list slice after you edit using list comprehension

```
[','.join(x).replace("'",'').split(',') for  x in lst][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

set will remove doublicates if exist in your nested list

```
 _list = [["'deliver","'ordered","'delivery","'delivering","'brought"],["'deliver","'offering","'providing","'delivers","'orders"]]

print(', '.join([*set([item for sublist in _list for item in sublist])]))
```

as normal way

```
print(', '.join([item for sublist in _list for item in sublist]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want duplicates or not? It's unclear from the question.

If you don't care about having duplicates, use a list comprehension:

```
print([string.strip("\'") for sublist in lst for string in sublist])
```

If you don't want duplicates, then use a set comprehension and convert it back to a list:

```
print(list({string.strip("\'") for sublist in lst for string in sublist}))
```

In both examples, we remove the inner single quotation from each string using the strip method, and once it is removed, python automatically converts the double quotes to single quotes. However, the fact that there are double quotes or single quotes doesn't matter, the items in the resulting lists still have type string. What kind of quotations only matters in cases mentioned here:

[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/single-and-double-quotes-python/#:~:text=Generally%2C%20double%20quotes%20are%20used,one%20type%20over%20the%20other](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/single-and-double-quotes-python/#:%7E:text=Generally%2C%20double%20quotes%20are%20used,one%20type%20over%20the%20other).